# Positioning jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, css-position

I want to position my jQuery dialog x-pixels away from the right border of the browser. Is this anyhow possible?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

The position option doesn't seem to have that kind of setup, but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI dialog positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744554/jquery-ui-dialog-positioning)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you make your dialog box's `position:absolute`, then its taken about of the regular page flow, and you can use the `left` and `top` property to place it anywhere on the page.

```
$('.selector').dialog({ dialogClass: 'myPosition' });
```

and define the myPosition css class as:

```
.myPosition {
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px; /* use a length or percentage */
}
```

You can set the `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` [properties](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_left.asp) for `myPosition` using either a length such as in pixels or percentage.

Comment: Don't forget that it will position it relative to the first parent element whose position is specified. If none are found, it is positioned relative to the body tag. Therefore, for a dialog like this, it's important to always append it to the body tag.

Answer (score 16):

This keeps dialog div in fixed position

this works for me in IE FF chrome and safari

```
jQuery("#dialogDiv").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, 
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 500,
    modal: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');
        $(event.target).parent().css('top', '5px');
        $(event.target).parent().css('left', '10px');
    }

});
```

when you want dialog box open just call

```
$('#dialogDiv').dialog('open');
```

Comment: +1 this worked better for me, because I need to be able to move the form around. Setting the position with a css class makes it frozen.

Answer (score 9):

Most of these answers seemed to be workarounds to me, and I wanted to find the official jQuery way to do it.  After reading through the `.position()` docs, I found that it can indeed be done in the initialization of the jQuery widget:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title:title,
    position:{my:"right top",at:"right+100 top+100", of:"body"},
    width:width,
    height:height
})
```

Where the +100 is the distance from the right and top respectively

Answer (score 5):

I understand the answer is already accepted but just in case if any one need more info:
http://salman-w.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/jquery-ui-dialog-examples.html

```
$(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                position: {
                    my: "right bottom",
                    at: "right bottom",
                    of: window
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

with this code u can specify ur top and left position:

```
$('#select_bezeh_window').dialog({
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
      draggable:false,
      width:40+'%',
      height:500 ,
      position:{
          using: function( pos ) {
                $( this ).css( "top", 10+'px' );
                $( this ).css( "left", 32+'%' );
          }
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position

Initialize a dialog with the position option specified.

```
 $('.selector').dialog({ position: 'top' });
```

Get or set the position option, after init.

```
//getter
var position = $('.selector').dialog('option', 'position');
//setter
$('.selector').dialog('option', 'position', 'top');
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me to display the dialog at the top-right corner with 10px offset: `position: "right-10 top+10"`:

```
$( "#my-dialog" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:"auto",
    width:350,
    autoOpen: false,
    position: "right-10 top+10"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix center position, I use:

```
open : function() {
    var t = $(this).parent(), w = window;
    t.offset({
        top: (w.height() / 2) - (t.height() / 2),
        left: (w.width() / 2) - (t.width() / 2)
    });
}
```