# Setting doctype for XDV theme

Tags: xslt, themes, plone, xdv

I have in my theme HTML file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
```

But in the page output I see (probably coming from main_template.pt):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

How can I use correct doctype information from my theme file?

Comment: What's the meaning for "correct DOCTYPE"?

Comment: This question is already discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://diazo.org/advanced.html?highlight=doctype#doctypes for how to do this in Diazo. I assume this also worked in XDV.

** EDIT:  the change the links structure.. 
 the current link is [Diazo typeDoc](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/advanced.html#doctypes)

Answer (score 0):

**How can I use correct doctype information from my theme file?**

I don't think you can. Almost nothing, except the ID attribute and unparsed entities' URIs, from a DTD is preserved in the XML Infoset (on which a transformation works) of the given XML document.

Were the document to have an XML Shema definition, then an XSLT 2.0 processor can be provided with this schema and can use it in very powerful ways.