# How do I prevent a locally stored XSLT rendered in IE8 defaulting to quirks mode?

Tags: xslt, quirks-mode

I have some very simple xml and xslt documents, which render in IE8 in quirks mode. However, I can't seem to turn it off. Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

seems to have no effect.

Is it possible to make it display in IE8 Standards mode?

Comment: @Dimitre: You appear to be in the enviable scenario of never having developed for IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a proper doctype:

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd";
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>
```

(I don't have an IE8 at hand so I cannot try - let me know if it works please ;) )

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. But what if I want an HTML5 doctype?

Comment: nvm, there's an answer to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt) elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Which solution did you pick for HTML5 doctype? Since Firefox doesn't support `disable-output-escaping`, you shouldn't use the top rated answer IMHO. Maybe you shouldn't use XSLT to produce HTML5 anyways, see [this discussion](http://markmail.org/message/er7ilpszibhmtene).

Comment: I did just go for the top answer. I might try some of the others, but at the moment, I'm not seeing any problems. The file will only bee seen by a small group anyway, most of them running IE8.