# How to output <!DOCTYPE html> with XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt)

I'm new to xslt and I'm trying to produce an HTML 5 document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

and Firefox gives me the error

```
"XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///E:/XSLT-XML-Shema/shipping-transform.xsl
Line Number 6, Column 4: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

If it's just `<html>` it works fine. How do I fix this and why does it happen?

--EDIT--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compact" />
<xsl:template match="/">
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Sample Corporation #1</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            Hello this is a test<br />
            Goodbye!
            </body>
            </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's a possible duplicate, but that thread it's hard to read. For "I'm new to XSLT" harder yet.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want absolutely the contracted form, your only choice is the `disable-output-escaping` of `xsl:text` as linked in the comments above. I think this is a bit dirty, and more, you have to indicate it within a template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternative cleaner solution, W3C defines for HTML5 a specific DOCTYPE legacy string that can be used by HTML generators which can't display the doctype in the shorter format. So, to stay with pure XSLT you can use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title>Sample Corporation #1</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                Hello this is a test<br />
                Goodbye!
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Still the same problem, am I doing it right?

Comment: @quest4knowledge: remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` under the root template and you are done!

Comment: I believe the XSLT processor in Firefox does not support disable-output-escaping (which is an optional feature and deprecated in XSLT 2.0).

Comment: @empo did that, then Firefox gives XML Parsing Error: 

mismatched tag. Expected: </xsl:template>.
Location: file:///H:/XSLT-XML-Shema/shipping-transform.xsl
Line Number 23, Column 4: </html>
----------^

Comment: @quest4knowledge: please paste somewhere the code you are testing.

Comment: I know adding <html> at the beginning of the template fixes this but isn't that unclean since that's what <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/> is doing?

Comment: @quest4knowledge: I've updated my answer with the correct implementation.

Comment: in my system the scape characters are not printed properly in the html file they stay &lt; and &gt;