# Unexpected char "!" error xpath

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I intend to generate a HTML5 page using xquery/xpath environment... Below is my page template function.

`(: Displays the page :)
    declare function mobunpage:display-page($pageinfo as element()) as element() {
        <!DOCTYPE HTML >
          <html>
        {mobunpage:get-head($pageinfo)}
            <body>
             {mobunpage:get-foot($pageinfo)}
            </body>
         </html>
};`

And with that I get and error:

"error found while loading module mobunpage: error found while loading module from modules/mobunpage.xqm: unexpected char: '!'"

I am running on an eXist XML database and getting the above error which comes when i add the  without the doctype the page works fine and display the parsed variables. Anyone know how to go about such error. Escaping doesn't solve the problem and tried a couple of functions from the documentation(http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) but with no luck so far. Will definitely appreciate some help. Thankies!

Answer (score 3):

The `<!DOCTYPE HTML >` isn't valid XQuery syntax.

If your XQuery engine supports definition of serialization options then there will be options doctype-system and doctype-public to set the system ID and public ID of the generated XML/HTML. It's unlikely it will support the new  syntax, but you should be able to use the alternative doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" as described in the lengthy thread [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt)