# The XML page cannot be displayed. Access is denied. Error processing resource

Tags: xml, iis, xslt

I have an xml page which has a stylesheet created. Locally within the network it works ok the style sheet displays the xml no prob. But when viewed externally, the xsl style sheet doesn't appear to be running ok or  Access is denied. Error processing resource.

It appears the xsl isn't allowing access to it..Does IIS have to be configured to allow .xsl file to be read?

I've given "everyone" full permissions on the web folder but still no luck.

Anyone come across this before?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The doctype generated by the XSLT is probably [being blocked by w3.org](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/). Try the [HTML5 legacy format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751243/1113772).