# error in doctype

Tags: php, xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is getting a parse error in DOCTYPE. how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The [W3C HTML 5 Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) recommends using `doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"`:**

> For compatibility with legacy producers of HTML — that is, software
>   that outputs HTML documents — an alternative DOCTYPE is available for
>   use by systems that are unable to output the DOCTYPE given above. This
>   limitation occurs in software that expects a DOCTYPE to include either
>   a PUBLIC or SYSTEM identifier, and is unable to omit them. The
>   canonical form of this DOCTYPE is as follows:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
> ```

You can achieve this with any XSLT processor with the following:

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
```

It will generate:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` declaration directly in xslt. Use the following:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
```

instead. See [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt) for a similar problem.

Comment: This solution will only work with a processor/environment that supports d-o-e; for example, it won't work in Firefox. See the cited question for more detail. Note with current versions of Saxon you can use `<xsl:output method='html' version='5'/>`