# Can't set a background image with CSS and XSL

Tags: css, xslt, background

I am trying to set a background image to a `<header>` tag into a XSL document with CSS but it's doesn't work (the image doesn't display).
The path of the image is correct. If I set the image with the `<img>`balise, It's work.

XSL code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf8" />
            <title>Bibliothèque</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="exercice9.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <header></header>
            ...
```

CSS code:

```
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header
{
    background: url(res/titre.gif");
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Thank :)

Comment: You have missed an opening ( " ) symbol at: `background: url(res/titre.gif");`

Comment: Also, make sure the CSS file has the same encoding as the xml file. And you misspelled `exercise`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Set the style of the `header` to the dimensions of the image
- Include the XHTML namespace in the root element:

  ```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          >
  ```
- Include the `xsl:output` element to set the HTML5 doctype:

  ```
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
  ```

**References**

- [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt/8751243#8751243)