# java transform to html with doctype

Tags: java, html

I am trying to create an html 5 output from java transformer.   I have

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

Element html= doc.createElement("html");
.... //populate the html element

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(html);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(fileLocation));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
```

This works great and creates the html file for me as I want.  but it doesn't have <!DOCTYPE html> at the top and I can't figure out how to get that.  Looking at the documentation on transformer I am only seeing how to turn on or off the xml version of the header.

As you can see in my code I tried to set the output keys method to html and I have tried to implement what is suggested [here](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/setting-doctype-to-a-dom-document.139420/) but the html files generated still don't have the doc type line.

Another option I have pondered is to create a doctype element but I don't know how to associate it with my html element.

Comment: The html output of the XSLT 1.0 transformation engine enclosed with Java predates HTML5 with more than a decade.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that

Comment: That does not make it impossible, just more difficult and most likely implementation dependent.

Comment: Found a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3404922/53897 looks best to me.

Comment: thank you @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen.  for anyone seeing this later.  I tried to run the xslt in the code above but because it didn't exist as a document yet all it did was strip all of the tags from the output.  I ended up importing the document created at the end of the above code and basically passing it through the above code again passing the xslt into the newTransformer(xslt);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this to line 5:

```
DOMImplementation domImpl = doc.getImplementation();
DocumentType doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType("");
doc.appendChild(doctype);
```

This will add the empty DocType (as usually used with HTML5).