# How to make Transformer not remove <!DOCTYPE html>?

Tags: java, xml

When I pass HTML5 code through a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype gets removed. Here is a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(
        IOUtils.toInputStream(
            Joiner.on('\n').join(
                "<!DOCTYPE html>",
                "<html>",
                "<head>",
                "</head>",
                "<body>",
                "</body>",
                "</html>"
            )
        )
    );
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(result));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println(
       result.toString()
    );
}
```

Output is:

```
<html>

<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

What can I do to preserve `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html ... xhtml">` IMHO don't work together. Just use `<html>`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I edited the post. The issue remains.

Comment: Init result as `result.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` - patchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOCTYPE declaration isn't part of the data model, so the XSLT transformer has no idea it is there, so it can't preserve it. Also, the syntax `<!DOCTYPE html>` wasn't around when XSLT 1.0 (and even 2.0) were standardised, so there's not even a standard way of generating it. But see [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt) for workarounds.