# Add a DOCTYPE declaration on XSL Ouptut

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming xml to another xml using XSLT. Some xmls will have DOCTYPE declaration and some donot. I am trying to insert doctype declaration from XSLT stylesheet but I couldn't find enough information on How to do that.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HTML5 doctype with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387127/set-html5-doctype-with-xslt). The accepted answer is outdated, but there is plenty of information in the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily add a doctype declaration with the xsl:output element:

```
<xsl:output 
    method="xml"
    standalone="no"
    doctype-public="-//Org//DTD XYZ 2017-02-06//DE"
    doctype-system="myStructure.dtd"
    />
```

With "doctype-public" you define the PUBLIC identifier and with "doctype-system" the filename of your DTD. The xsl:output element typically is at the top of your XSL right after xsl:stylesheet (or xsl:import if any).