# jQuery UI modal dialog, position module underneath/relative to link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i am trying to position my jQuery dialogue modal relative to the to the link that reveals the module. What I ideally like is to open the module directly centered underneath the link.

Below is my code, how would I change this to get the desired effect?

```
$("#tooltest").bind("click", function (e) {
  $("#LightboxTool").dialog({ 
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    modal: false,
    width: 320,
    minHeight: 180  
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Adapted answer to blog post: http://www.jensbits.com/2011/06/19/position-jquery-ui-dialog-relative-to-link/ Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 4):

keithnorm has answered this greatly in a [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-position-a-dialog-relative-to-a-div-instead-of-relative-to-the-viewport) as follows:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    position: { 
        my: 'top',
        at: 'top',
        of: $('#some_div')
    }
});
```

An also this question looks a like a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744554/jquery-ui-dialog-positioning).