# Page automatically go to the top when opening a jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery

Every time I click my button at the bottom to open the jquery dialog box, the page will automatically scroll to the top. I'm using firefox browser.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744554/jquery-ui-dialog-positioning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have to prevent the default operation of the button

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    // .... open dialog.
});
```

OR you have to return false on the onclick event of button

```
<input type="button" value="My Button" onclick="openDialog();return false;" />
```

Comment: You forgot the event argument