# Change position of popup dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I am trying to display a popup dialog that reads "Saved successfully" when a user clicks on save button.

In Html, I have

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isSaved = '<%= this.showSavedDialog %>';
        if (isSaved)
        {
            $("#savedDialog").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'left bottom',
                    at: 'right top',
                    of: ("#btnSave")
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server">Save</asp:LinkButton>

<div id="savedDialog">
    Saved successfully
</div>
```

and in the code behind, I have

```
protected bool showSavedDialog
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["showSavedDialog"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SessionExpired.aspx");
        }
        return bool.Parse(Session["showSavedDialog"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

I do get the popup dialog when I click the Save button. But, the problem is that the Save button is far down the page and the dialog is displayed on top of the page, so I have to scroll all up to click the "OK" button on the dialog. I've found solutions about how to change the position of the dialog, but no matter how I set it up, the display is positioned on the top of the page or right under the save button(that's where the actually html code for the dialog, "savedDialog", is). 
What am I missing here to change the position of the dialog? I'm very new with jquery so I would appreciate any help. 
Ideally, I want to display it in the center of the page, or at least, I want it to be right next to the save button.

Comment: The answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010540/position-jquery-ui-dialog?lq=1 should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer for my own question. Here's what I did.

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isSaved = '<%= this.showSavedDialog %>';
        if (isSaved)
        {
            $("#savedDialog").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                position: {
                    my: "bottom",
                    at: "top",

                    //used div instead of a button so the dialog can be centered     
                    of: ("#div-save") 

                    //I needed this the dialog can be displayed at the bottom of the page
                    collison: "none"                     
                    }
            });
        }
    });

</script>

<div id="div-save">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server">Save</asp:LinkButton>
</div>

<div id="savedDialog">
    Saved successfully
</div>
```

**CS:**

```
protected bool showSavedDialog
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["showSavedDialog"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SessionExpired.aspx");
        }
        return bool.Parse(Session["showSavedDialog"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#div-save
{
    float:left;
    width: 935px;
}
```